# not opening database file

Tags: bibtex

these lines are in my tex

```
 \section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{agsm} 
\bibliography{figure.bib}
\end{document}
```

and I receive these below errors

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
The style file: agsm.bst
I couldn't open database file figure.bib
---line 103 of file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
 : \bibdata{figure.bib
 :                    }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Tsaur2007"
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Solomon2016"
```

Comment: BibTeX says it can't find your `.bib` file `figure.bib`. Is your `.bib` file actually called `figure.bib` (double check that it is really called `figure.bib` and not `figure.bib.tex` or `figure.bib.txt`, when dealing with TeX it is usually wise to disable Windows' option to hide known file extensions: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1784.windows-how-to-view-file-name-extensions.aspx)? Is it in the same folder as your main `.tex` file?

Comment: This does not appear to be the underlying problem here, but note that `\bibliography` takes the file name **without** extension. So **the correct call is `\bibliography{figure}`** and not `\bibliography{figure.bib}`. On some systems the incorrect `.bib` *will* cause problems (on my MikTeX system I'll get complaints that `figure.bib.bib` can't be found), TeX live is usually a bit more forgiving. But this should still be fixed, even if it doesn't resolve the problem at hand.

Comment: In \bibliography{} , in that {}, I have to put the address of my bib ?am I right? I have folder in desktop named "figure" and my bib named S.M.R.ARTICLES.bib is there, I even put S.M.R.ARTICLES.bib out of this folder on desktop and remove the name of figure folder, and then run, and even just like what u said right the name of {figure} only, but in all that trying I ve just received these errors again, would u kindly please help me? many thanks

Comment: Put the `.bib` file into the same folder as your `.tex` file. That will make things *much* easier. Then you only need to give the (base) name of your `.bib` file. Nothing more. Otherwise you will have to deal with either giving the full absolute path or a relative path.

Comment: I wrote my article on elsarticle-template , but when I put that as my .tex  on the mentioned folder (figure) the first run(pdfLaTeX) do not run, so i removed it to my desktop then. and give the name of my bib, but I received that errors again

Comment: here it is the errors:             
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
The style file: agsm.bst
I couldn't open database file S.M.R.ARTICLE.bib
---line 103 of file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
 : \bibdata{S.M.R.ARTICLE
 :                       }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no database files---while reading file elsarticle-template-last SMR..aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "Tsaur2007"

Comment: Don't move the `.tex` file to the folder of the `.bib` file, copy the `.bib` file into the folder of your `.tex` file. If you are using a template, chances are your `.tex` file depends on some other files (`.sty` files for example, included `.tex` files) in the same folder. If you move the `.tex` file, it won't be able to find those files. For your sanity I suggest you avoid file names with dots (`.`) in them.

Comment: Thanks moewe , I  change the name my folder in Mendeley without dots then make new bib file and put both bib file and elsarticle temple on the desktop not on any folder and then write the complete adress of bib  in \bibliography{c:/users/sarah/desktop/SMRARTICLE}, then it completely run. thank you